# How do several INSERT and SELECT statements work in a common table expression?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I am trying to import xbrl file into Postgres via arelle. It generates the following sql:

```
WITH row_values (report_id, document_id, xml_id, xml_child_seq, source_line, parent_datapoint_id, aspect_id, context_xml_id, entity_identifier_id, period_id, aspect_value_selection_id, unit_id, is_nil, precision_value, decimals_value, effective_value, value) AS 
(
  VALUES (3150993::bigint, 3150994::bigint, NULL, '/1/5', 36::integer, NULL::bigint, 22904::bigint, 'c-01', 3151029::bigint, 3151079::bigint, 3162474::bigint, 3150995::bigint, FALSE::boolean, NULL, '0', 1580::double precision, '1580'),
         (3150993, 3150994, NULL, '/1/6', 37, NULL, 22979, 'c-01', 3151029, 3151079, 3162474, NULL, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, '011X0082'),
  -- more values here
         (3150993, 3150994, NULL, '/1/7700166', 12475343, NULL, 22625, 'c-387173', 3151076, 3151079, 3254880, NULL, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2017-05-01')
), insertions AS (
   INSERT INTO data_point (report_id, document_id, xml_id, xml_child_seq, source_line, parent_datapoint_id, aspect_id, context_xml_id, entity_identifier_id, period_id, aspect_value_selection_id, unit_id, is_nil, precision_value, decimals_value, effective_value, value)
   SELECT report_id, document_id, xml_id, xml_child_seq, source_line, parent_datapoint_id, aspect_id, context_xml_id, entity_identifier_id, period_id, aspect_value_selection_id, unit_id, is_nil, precision_value, decimals_value, effective_value, value
  FROM row_values v
  RETURNING datapoint_id, document_id, xml_child_seq
)
SELECT datapoint_id, document_id, xml_child_seq
FROM insertions;
```

How `with`, `insert into` and multiple select statements can live in single instruction (there is no one `;`)?

Comment: Add a comment when downvote. I am not expert in postgres at all.

Comment: I suggest checking out the PostgreSQL [documentation for the `WITH` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html). I linked to the newest release. Please refine your question after reading the docs. Making the snippet more readable will also help people to answer your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It's a data [modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING).

However, the way it's structured, it is **way** too complicated.

The whole statement can be simplified to:

```
INSERT INTO data_point (....)
VALUES (...),
       (...),
        ...
       (...)
returning datapoint_id, document_id, xml_child_seq;
```

---

The first CTE simply defines the rows to be inserted. Outside of a CTE you can do that as well:

```
select *
from ( values (1,2), (2,3)) as dummy(x,y);
```

The values from the first CTE are then used by the second CTE as the source of the `insert ... select` statement. It uses the `returning` clause so that the `INSERT` results in a set of rows that are then used the final SELECT statement to display them.

---

If the goal was to separate the values and the INSERT, then this could have been done in the final SELECT statement of the CTE as well:

Something like this:

```
WITH row_values as (...) 
(
  VALUES (...),
         (...),
          ...
         (...)
) 
INSERT INTO data_point (....)
SELECT ...
FROM row_values
returning datapoint_id, document_id, xml_child_seq;
```

Still needlessly complicated in my opinion (compared to the simple `insert .. values ..` version).

---

As to *why*  Arelle created such a mess I can't say.